# how to add rating for columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categories

I would like add some rating or caterogicl for my dataframe and add extra columsn for it. For example `positiv = 1`, `negative = 0`, `neutral = 2`. Im trying do but it is not what i want.

```
output:tweet_id airline_sentiment Raiting
0 570306133677760513 neutral NaN
1 570301130888122368 positive NaN
2 570301083672813571 neutral NaN
```

```
                                    : ##cate##
df1.airline_sentiment = df1.airline_sentiment.astype('category')
df1['Raiting'] = df1.airline_sentiment.cat.set_categories([1, 2,3])
df1
```

Answer (score 3):

Use mapping

```
sentiment_dict = {'positive': 1, 'negative': 0, 'neutral': 2}

df1['airline_sentiment'].map(sentiment_dict)
```

Comment: Thanks, but when i run df1 still i see only two columns without Ratinf e.g